# %b vs %B in datetime module (python 3)

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, strptime

```
fmt_1 = '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
fmt_2 = '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'

t1="Sat 14 Sep 2126 00:36:44 +1400"
code1= dateime.datime.strptime(t1,fmt_1)  #run time error

code2= dateime.datime.strptime(t1,fmt_2)   #right code
```

**I got runtime error for fmt_1 for this and fixed by using fmt_2**

*what is difference between %b and %B?*

Comment: Make it into a habit of **posting the full stack trace** please. Makes life easier when you want help.

Comment: I'm assuming you notice the typo in datetime.datetime? Can you fix it and try posting the error again?

Comment: Simply [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) as they are well defined there. But as Prateek said, your issue is most likely just a spelling issue.

Comment: Additionally, %b signifies abbreviated month name (just the first 3 letters), while %B signifies the full month name. That's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation about Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

- `%b` is for Month as locale’s abbreviated name. Like `Jan, Feb, …, Dec`
- `%B` is for Month as locale’s full name. Like `January, February, …, December`

---

In `Sat 14 Sep 2126 00:36:44 +1400` the month `Sep` is in `abbreviated` format so `%b` fits, wher `%B` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

**%b** use for locale’s abbreviated month name and **%B** use for full month name.
**t1="Sat 14 Sep 2126 00:36:44 +1400"** is this string **Sep** is short name. that's why you are getting error in fmt_1 for format mismatch.
You can follow this doc https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/datetime.html

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Sat 14 Sep 2126 00:36:44 +1400", '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and get the following result:

```
'2126-09-14 00:36:44'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question